# Enviar parametro de data sem as barras "/" no metodo GET do PHP

Tags: php, javascript, datepicker, zurb-foundation

Tenho um formulário de booking que envia os dados para uma URL e na página da URL os dados são tratados. Contudo tenho o problema, a URL não consegue ler a variável dos campos data, pois o date picker envia os parâmetros com barra "/".

Estou utilizando o datepicker do Foundation.

http://jsfiddle.net/thallysondias/6e03wgLL/

```js
$(function () {
    window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint();
    $('#dp1').fdatepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    });
    $('#dp2').fdatepicker({
        closeButton: true
    });
    
    // implementation of disabled form fields
    var nowTemp = new Date(); 
    var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    var checkin = $('#dpd1').fdatepicker({
        onRender: function (date) {
            return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
        }
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
            var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
            newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
            checkout.update(newDate);
        }
        checkin.hide();
        $('#dpd2')[0].focus();
    }).data('datepicker');
    var checkout = $('#dpd2').fdatepicker({
        onRender: function (date) {
            return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
        }
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        checkout.hide();
    }).data('datepicker');
});
```

```html
<link href="http://luteciahotel.com/css/foundation-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://luteciahotel.com/js/datepicker/foundation-datepicker.js"></script>



<!-- INICIO BOOKING -->
<div id="booking" class="booking show-for-medium-up">
    <div class="row"> 
        <form action="https://reservations.omnibees.com/default.aspx" method="GET" target="_blank">    
            <input type="hidden" id="q" name="q" value="1316" />  
            <input type="hidden" id="lang" name="lang" value="pt-PT" />
            <div class="medium-2 columns">
                <input type="text" value="" id="dpd1" placeholder="Check-in" name="CheckIn" readonly/>
            </div>
            <div class="medium-2 columns">
                <input type="text" value="" id="dpd2" name="CheckOut" placeholder="Check-out" readonly/>
            </div>
            <div class="medium-2 columns">
                <select id="ad" name="ad">
                    <option value="1" selected>Adulto</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="medium-2 columns">
                <select id="ch" name="ch">
                    <option value="0" selected>Criança</option>
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="medium-2 columns">
                <input type="text" name="Code" id="Code" placeholder="cod. promocial"/>
            </div>
            <div class="medium-2 columns">
                <input type="submit" class="button expand tiny" style="margin:0;border:0 !important;" value="Reservar">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!--/ FIM BOOKING -->
```

Neste momento a o valor da data fica com este formato na URL
CheckIn=`31%2F01%2F2015`&CheckOut=`18%2F03%2F2015`.

Impossibilitando assim a leitura correta da variavel, pois o correto seria:
CheckIn=`31012015`&CheckOut=`18032015`.

Removendo o valor `%2F`.

Como eu poderia enviar a variavel sem a "/" do datepicker?

Vi algo assim:

```
var textarea = $('#the_textarea');
var txt = textarea.val();
textarea.val(txt.replace(' ', '-'));
```

Mas não estou sabendo como usar!

Comment: Vc não conseguiria interceptar o envio pelo submit e retirar as barras por `javascript`?

Comment: Ola @GustavoCinque, como eu poderia fazer isso? Que acho que posso sim

Comment: Eu acho que, simples, colocar um `onSubmit` na tag do `form` e executar um `return` de um método que retiraria as barras e retornaria `true`. Vale uma tentativa. (`onSubmit="return metodo()"`)

Comment: Eu sei que é viavel fazer isso, mas como fazer não saberia dizer, sou péssimo em Js, deixarei para alguem que tenha mais confiança :D

Comment: Obrigado pela luz @GustavoCinque, vou tentar fazer alguma coisa.

Comment: Por que não usar o formato padrão do ISO 8601 (`YYYY-MM-DD`)? É até mais simples (além de correto) de fazer as consultas e cálculos com as datas. Pra converter você pode usar estas técnicas: http://rberaldo.com.br/php-conversao-de-datas-formato-brasileiro-e-formato-iso/

Comment: @Beraldo, porq eu tenho q passar essa url para um serviço externo, ele le o ID da data e exibe os valores e os valores devem ser sempre ddmmaaaa

Comment: Vi que posso utilizar o `str.replace(' ', '-');` mas não estou sabendo como usar

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/KyleKatarn/6e03wgLL/2/

A solução era usar o replace:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    $('#dpd1').val( $('#dpd1').val().replace(/\//g, '') );
    $('#dpd2').val( $('#dpd2').val().replace(/\//g, '') );
});
```